# Bootstrap + JQuery: How break lines of spans in div dynamically created by append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm appending dynamically  into  using jquery .append command. I have problem with rendering multiple lines. If I add too many spans  that do not fit in one line, next span is not moving to second line. All spans are still in one line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
      addTag($("div#tag-line"),"tag");
    });
});

function addTag(tagField, tagValue) {
  tag = '<span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">' + tagValue + '</span>'
  tagField.append(tag);
  tagField.hide().fadeIn('fast')
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tags" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Tags</label>
  <button>
  add
  </button>
  <h4>
    <div id="tag-line" class="col-xs-6" style="border: 2px solid red">
    </div> 
  </h4>
</div>
```

When span is not added dynamicly everythings looks fine:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tags" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Tags</label>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield"/>
  </div>
  <button>
  add
  </button>
  <h4>
    <div id="tag-line" class="col-xs-6" style="border: 2px solid red">
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
      <span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">asda</span>
    </div> 
  </h4>
</div>
```

I'm bootstrap and jquery beginner and I'm convinced that I had to overlook something. I was looking for a similar example on the stack but could not find anything. Please help! :)

Comment: The difference between the two is that there is whitespace between the spans in the pure html example which doesn't exist in the javascript one.  Consider a span to be the same as a letter, and think about how a line of text would break if there were no spaces between any of the letters, vs a line of text that has spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your dynamically added example and the hard coded one is white space. Each `<span></span>\n<span></span>` is on it's own line in the hard coded example so there's a white space character in between each one. When you're dynamically adding them, they're all one one line with no characters in between them `<span></span><span></span>`

You can fix this by putting a space right after the span at the end of your dynamically injected markup.

```
tag = '<span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px">' + tagValue + '</span> '
```

However, I think a more correct approach would be with CSS, changing the label's display to inline-block:

```
#tag-line .label { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Both cases work. I chose this one with CSS. 
Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Change the .label display: inline to inline-block;

```
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

You have to add css to move span to next line.

and i also used `min-height` and `max-height` and `overflow-y` for scroll down your div if there is a more tabs.

Hope this will helps you. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
      addTag($("div#tag-line"),"tag");
    });
});

function addTag(tagField, tagValue) {
  tag = '<span class="label label-info" style="margin: 2px; display: inline-block">' + tagValue + '</span>'
  tagField.append(tag);
  tagField.hide().fadeIn('fast')
}
```

```css
#tag-line 
{min-height:50px; max-height: 200px; max-width: 300px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y: scroll;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tags" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Tags</label>
  <button>
  add
  </button>
  <h4>
    <div id="tag-line" class="col-xs-6" style="border: 2px solid red">
    </div> 
  </h4>
</div>
```